# Ошибка 405 Method not Allowed во время axios post Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

Вот решил выучить Vue.js и Laravel. Но застрял на ошибке `405 Method not Allowed`.
Пытаюсь через `axios.post(...)` отправить картинку, но в ответ та самая ошибка. Смотрел решения этой проблемы, почти везде советуют менять первый аргумент в `axios.post(...)`, но мне такое решение ошибку не исправляет. Теперь сам прошу помощи. Знаю, что скорее всего решение банально. Буду очень благодарен.

Вот `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/', 'FilesUploadController@index');
Route::post('upload', 'FilesUploadController@upload');
```

Вот `FilesUploadController.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FilesUploadController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function upload( Request $request) {
        return json_encode($request->all());
    }
}
```

Вот Компонент `Vue.js`:

```
<template>
    <div class="upload-component">

        <div class="progress-bar-container">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
        </div>

        <input type="file" name="files" multiple="" @change="upload">

        <div class="lists">
            <div class="list-container">
                <ul class="filesOrder">
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="list-container">
                <ul class="filesUploaded">
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            upload: function () {
                let file = new FormData();

                file.append('file', event.target.files);
                console.log(file);
                axios.post('/upload', file)
                    .then (
                        (response) => { console.log(response) },
                        (error) => { console.log(error) }
                    );
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Вот ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: / добавьте в роуте перед upload

Comment: почему `web.php`, а не `api.php`. Вы же запросы через axios шлёте со спец. заголовком. И laravel пытается найти роут для api. А его нет. Вот и ошибка - запрашиваемый метод не разрешён.

Comment: Перенёс последнюю строку в api.php, теперь ошибка 404.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::post('/upload', 'FilesUploadController@upload');
```

Comment: Ошибка не изменилась

Answer (score 0):

Для начала убедитесь что у вас присутствует защищенное соединение, `javascript` требует его для отправки запроса, если вы используете локальный сервер, то, предположительно, его нет. Самый быстрый вариант это запустить `ngrok` сервер.
Просто скачайте `ngrok`, авторизируйтесь, скачайте `ngrok` и добавьте в `path` и прямо на странице get-started вам дадут команды, после того как сделайте все с get-started идите в папку с вашим `laravel` приложением, выполните `php artisan serve` и после запустите команду `ngrok http localhost:8000`(вместо localhost:8000 адрес на котором запущено ваше приложение)
И если после этого ошибка остается, то скорее всего вы не передали `csrf token` ключ который `laravel` требует для `post` запросов. Вам нужно отправить ключ в заголовке вашего запроса (в вашем случае `axios`)[(момент в документации)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token), т.е. измените свой запрос на такой:

```js
axios.post('/upload', file, {
    headers: { // объект в котором передаются заголовки запроса
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.getElementById("post_token").getAttribute("content") // запрос который содержит ваш токен
    }
}).then (
    (response) => { console.log(response) },
    (error) => { console.log(error) }
);
```

Как вы уже поняли на странице (в .html) должен быть `meta` тег, примерно такой:

```html
<meta id="post_token" name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```