# Ошибка 404 при отправлении пост запроса через axios.post(...) в Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

Вот решил выучить Vue.js и Laravel. Но застрял на ошибке `405 Method not Allowed`.
Пытаюсь через `axios.post(...)` отправить картинку, но в ответ та самая ошибка. Смотрел решения этой проблемы, почти везде советуют менять первый аргумент в `axios.post(...)`, но мне такое решение ошибку не исправляет. Теперь сам прошу помощи. Знаю, что скорее всего решение банально. Буду очень благодарен.

Вот `api.php`:

```
Route::post('upload', 'FilesUploadController@upload');
```

Вот `FilesUploadController.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FilesUploadController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function upload( Request $request) {
        return json_encode($request->all());
    }
}
```

Вот Компонент `Vue.js`:

```
<template>
    <div class="upload-component">

        <div class="progress-bar-container">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
        </div>

        <input type="file" name="files" multiple="" @change="upload">

        <div class="lists">
            <div class="list-container">
                <ul class="filesOrder">
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="list-container">
                <ul class="filesUploaded">
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            upload: function () {
                let file = new FormData();

                file.append('file', event.target.files);
                console.log(file);
                axios.post('/upload', file)
                    .then (
                        (response) => { console.log(response) },
                        (error) => { console.log(error) }
                    );
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте добавить / - `Route::post('/upload', 'FilesUploadController@upload');`. Также после попробуйте сделать этот роут get в web.php и открыть страницу через браузер, отобразив там что-нибудь. И посмотрите в хроме в панели url запроса вашего из axios. Покопайтесь там, в общем.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка 405 Method not Allowed во время axios post Laravel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927069/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-405-method-not-allowed-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-axios-post-laravel)

Comment: Ну я пытался покопаться... Когда я меняю в axios.post(...) первый аргумент и/или первый аргумент в Route::post(...), то ошибка( скриншот добавил в вопрос ) совершенно не меняется(сссылка в ошибке остаётся неизменной).

Comment: ваш проект есть на гитхабе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из-за того, что Вы прописали route'инг в файле `api.php` - путь будет доступен только по адресу `/api/upload`.
Для того, чтобы сделать его доступным по адресу `/upload`, то путь надо прописать в `web.php`.

[image: Routes list]